# Uploaded files to azure blob storage are empty or not even present

Tags: python, azure

I can upload files to Azure, but sometimes the files I send to Azure are empty or not even present. I use `iothub_client` (from `azure-iothub-device-client`).

First I create a series of csv and json files from an SQL database which I temporarily store on my pc. These files are then processed by the upload client and uploaded asynchronously to a storage blob.
Basically the structure is:
-- ID
---- csv file
---- csv file
---- json file

Most of the time this functions without any problems, however sometimes something doesn't work correctly and one csv file is containing only the header row - but never all of them - and/or the json file is even missing. The order of uploading is:

1. csv file one
2. json file
3. csv file two

The files are however always correctly created and stored on my pc. The code does not give any errors, so the `iothub_client` seems to be happy with what it's getting as input.

I can't figure out why this goes wrong, as I have not been able to reproduce the error. Retrying to upload the same files results in a correctly executed upload procedure.

Any clues about what can be the cause would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. have you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I run into this a lot. My best guess something has a lock on the file. I team into this with a logic app that scanned a SharePoint directory every five minutes. It would grab an Excel file and move it to blob storage. But I kept getting 0k files. I haven't seen this issue since changing the logic app too check every ten minutes. This increases the odds that a user will not be in the file.